# Bug in Mono C# compiler's implementation of yield?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, dmcs

This code causes an internal compiler error at the if(false) statement, using the 2.10.8 dmcs as well as MonoTouch. Is this known? (This may be a bug report, but I could be doing something lame.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
class X
{
    static int Main()
    {
       foreach(var i in GetAll())
       {
       }

       return 0;
    }
    static IEnumerable GetAll()
    {
       yield return 1;
       if (false)
          yield return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Internal compiler errors are *always* compiler bugs IMO.

Comment: Please fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: I can see how this went undiagnosed for so long.

Comment: @poupou, if you or someone else has a bugzilla account, could you please do the needful? I want to avoid yet another conduit for email spam - and bugzilla makes plain that email addresses are not kept private.

Comment: filled as https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3553

Comment: Bug is now marked fixed.